# I want to cut few lines from my log file after matching the condition

Tags: shell

I have huge log file, i want to delete lines starting from `---Successful backups---` until starting with line `---Failed backups---`. Then again want to delete lines starting from `---Unresolved clients---` until `---Summary notification report---` using shell script. Below is the example of few logs. Please suggest.

```
---Summary notification report--- Policy name:xyz
        Workflow name:abc1, Workflow status:succeeded, Workflow start time:08/01/23 14:30:00, Duration:0 hours 0 minutes 33 seconds
                Action name:backup, Action status:succeeded, Action start time:08/01/23 14:30:00, Duration:0 hours 0 minutes 33 seconds
--- Traditional Backup Action report --- Policy name:xyz Workflow name:abc1 Action name:backup Action status:succeeded Action start time:08/01/23 14:35:00 Action duration:0 hours 0 minutes 30 seconds Total 1 client(s), 0 Succeeded with warning(s), 1 Succeeded, 0 Failed, 0 Unresolved.
        ---Successful backups---
        abc.net:PIP, level=incr, size 96 KB, duration 0 hours 0 minutes 14 seconds, 5 files
        abc.net:SYBASE:/PIP/master.1, level=full, size 20 MB, duration 0 hours 0 minutes 2 seconds, 1 files
        ---Successful backups with warnings---
        none
        ---Failed backups---
        none
        ---Unresolved clients---
        none
---Summary notification report---
```

I am trying to use grep command but not getting the correct result.

```
cat log.out | grep -A 7 'Action name:backup, Action status:failed, Action start time:08/01/23'
```

Comment: Share an expected output as well. If you're trying to extract only failed backups, you can use `sed` to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

If "until starting with line `"---Failed backups---"` means delete from the start but stop and do not delete this line, (and the same for `"---Summary notification report---"`), then you can do it fairly easily with `awk` just by toggling a flag that controls whether you delete (skip) printing the record. For example you can do:

```bash
awk '
  # set del flag 1, skip to next record (line)
  /^[[:space:]]*---Successful backups---/ { del=1; next }
  # set del flag 0
  /^[[:space:]]*---Failed backups---/ { del=0 } 
  # set del flag 1, skip to next record (line)
  /^[[:space:]]*---Unresolved clients---/ { del=1; next } 
  # set del flag 0
  /^[[:space:]]*---Summary notification report---$/ { del=0 } 
  # if del set, skip printing record
  del {next}
  # otherwise print
  {print}
' dat/log
```

Where you simply condition each rule (the commands between `{ ... }`) with a regular expression to match your start and stop lines. The `del` flag controls whether the line will be skipped (not printed). You turn the `del` flag on when you match a record containing your start-rule (not printing that line) and your turn the `del` flag off when you reach your end rule (outputting that record). You can combine the on and off rules using an `||` (OR) condition between the regular expressions -- but that makes it a bit less readable.

**Example Use/Output**

With your sample data in the file `dat/log` you can simply paste the command at the prompt while in a directory (or providing the complete path to) your data file, e.g.:

```
$ awk '
>   # set del flag 1, skip to next record (line)
>   /^[[:space:]]*---Successful backups---/ { del=1; next }
>   # set del flag 0
>   /^[[:space:]]*---Failed backups---/ { del=0 }
>   # set del flag 1, skip to next record (line)
>   /^[[:space:]]*---Unresolved clients---/ { del=1; next }
>   # set del flag 0
>   /^[[:space:]]*---Summary notification report---$/ { del=0 }
>   # if del set, skip printing record
>   del {next}
>   # otherwise print
>   {print}
> ' dat/log
---Summary notification report--- Policy name:xyz
        Workflow name:abc1, Workflow status:succeeded, Workflow start time:08/01/23 14:30:00, Duration:0 hours 0 minutes 33 seconds
                Action name:backup, Action status:succeeded, Action start time:08/01/23 14:30:00, Duration:0 hours 0 minutes 33 seconds
--- Traditional Backup Action report --- Policy name:xyz Workflow name:abc1 Action name:backup Action status:succeeded Action start time:08/01/23 14:35:00 Action duration:0 hours 0 minutes 30 seconds Total 1 client(s), 0 Succeeded with warning(s), 1 Succeeded, 0 Failed, 0 Unresolved.
        ---Failed backups---
        none
---Summary notification report---
```

Let me know if you need to skip your stop lines or remove your start lines. Whether you intended to be *inclusive* or *exclusive* in what to remove was a bit ambiguous. To change the behavior, either add or remove a `next` in the rule to skip or print the start/stop line.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed` :

```bash
sed -e '/---Successful backups---/,/---Failed backups---/{/---Failed backups---/!d}' -e '/---Unresolved clients---/,/---Summary notification report---/{/---Summary notification report---/!d}' log.out
```

- `/addr1/,/addr2/` will match from line that match `addr1` to line that match `addr2`
- `/addr/!` if line does not match `addr`
- `d` delete

Comment: Thank you,

please suggest how can i use date condition as well?
eg:
sed -e '/---Summary notification report---/,/Workflow start time:08/01/23/{/Workflow start time:08/01/23/!d}' log.out

Comment: @SwapnilDagar, I'd gladly update my answer, but I'm not sure to understand your demand. Could you update your question adding these element : an expected output, is your date condition static or does it come from a var/command, does you log.out contains multiple workflow or is it one log per workflow ?

Comment: log.out contains logs from each date. So i want to exclude all logs from previous date except from today's date. Expected output as below.
log files contais data like this.
        Workflow name:abc, Workflow status:succeeded, Workflow start time:07/31/23 18:30:00, Duration:0 hours 2 minutes 11 seconds
        Workflow name:abc, Workflow status:succeeded, Workflow start time:08/01/23 18:30:00, Duration:0 hours 2 minutes 11 seconds
now I want all logs only from 08/01/23.

Comment: log.out contains multiple line. So grep is not displaying correct result.

Policy name:Server Protection
        Workflow name:abc, Workflow status:succeeded, Workflow start time:08/01/23 18:30:00, Duration:0 hours 2 minutes 11 seconds
Workflow name:LOG_SYB_1HOURLY_0_000_000_01_000
                
Policy name:Server Protection
        Workflow name:abc, Workflow status:succeeded, Workflow start time:08/01/23 18:30:00, Duration:0 hours 2 minutes 11 seconds
Workflow name:LOG_FS_1HOURLY_0_001_000_01_000

Answer (score 0):

Using the [TXR](http://nongnu.org/txr) Lisp [`awk`](https://www.nongnu.org/txr/txr-manpage.html#N-000264BC) macro, this can be done directly, without any state flags:

```
$ txr -e '(awk ((or (rng- #/---Successful backups---/
                          #/---Failed backups---/)
                    (rng- #/---Unresolved clients---/
                          #/---Summary notification report---/))
                (next))
               (t))'   < infile > outfile
```

The Awk range syntax `from, to` looks like `(rng from to)`. However, there are two more differences:

1. the [`rng`](https://www.nongnu.org/txr/txr-manpage.html#N-01A056E4) operator comes in nine usefully different flavors.
2. range expressions can be used as subexpressions in larger expressions, which is not permitted in regular Awk.

In the above solution we use `rng-` which excludes the ending record, and we use the `(or ...)` macro to combine the two ranges that we want to exclude into a single expression. For these ranges we call `(next)` to go to the next record. Otherwise control falls through to the (t) clause, which has an unconditionally true condition `t`, and an empty action, so the default action is `(prn)` to print the record.